# How to filter a similar field in multiple joined table

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, innodb

I have a query that works fine now but I am concerned about scalability and performance.

This query is used to search a word in tables t2 and t3 and return filtered result that matched in `t1`. `t1` is a many to many table.

*The objective*:
I have 3 tables where the user (`user_id`) can insert records. If the `user_id` is having evil intentions and create inappropriate content in any of the 3 tables, **I want to be able to filter quickly his content**. I could delete instantaneously everything the `user_id` created from the user table as I use innoDB but I want to keep a trace of `user_id` behavior for further analysis later.

*The situation*:

- I have a similar field `user_id` in three joined table `t1`, `t2`, `t3`.
- I search a word (`src_wd`) in any of the tables `t2` and `t3`.
- If `src_word` is in `t2` or `t3`, then return the result from `t1` that is `t2.id`.
- If an evil user, I set the user to `user.is_active = 0`

*The look of the **table t1***:

```
|t1.id|t1.user_id|t2.id|t3.id|
|  2  |   158    |  20 | 32  |
|  3  |   165    |  20 | 34  |
|  4  |   199    |  24 | 36  |
```

*My current query*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.id

FROM t1

LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id 
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.user_id = t1.user_id 

LEFT JOIN user u1 ON u1.user_id = t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON u2.user_id = t2.user_id
LEFT JOIN user u3 ON u3.user_id = t3.user_id

WHERE 
u1.is_active != 0 AND u2.is_active != 0 AND u3.is_active != 0 
AND
t2.srcField LIKE '%$src_wd%' OR t3.srcField LIKE '%$src_wd%'
```

*My concern*:

My concern is related to the **multiple joins on the `user` table** `u1` `u2` `u3` I do to get the result I want.

I could optimize later, but I'm learning, so why not trying the good way starting now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues:

- `LIKE '%...'` (leading wild card) leads to a full table scan -- not scalable.  Think about `FULLTEXT` indexing.
- `WHERE this AND that OR other` is performed `WHERE (this AND that) OR other`, which is probably not what you wanted.  When mixing `AND` and `OR`, add parentheses to avoid goofs.
- Flags (such as `is_active`) do not help in scaling.  However, there is not necessarily a better way.
- `is_active != 0` -- Was this a clever way to check for `NULL` (due to `LEFT JOIN`) at the same time?  See also the operator `<=>`.
- Do you need `LEFT` in all 4 cases?
- `t1` is a many:many mapping -- but between what two tables?  (I see 3 columns that seem like links to other tables.)  See my [*efficiency*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) tips on such.
- It might help to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: When I see your answer, I realize how imprecise my question is. I'll add more details asap.

Comment: You may be a 'gentle'boy; I was feeling 'gentle' in my Answer.  I'll look again after you add the details.